# Redirect route does not redirect to a specified route in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have following component.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

const SampleComponent = (props) => {
  const onOverlayHandle = () => {
    console.log('overlay clicked');
    return <Redirect to='/feedback' />
  }

    return (
    <div className='view dialog'>
      <div className='form'>
        <h3>CONTENTS</h3>
      </div>
      <div className='overlay' onClick={onOverlayHandle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (state);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SampleComponent);
```

As you can see that there is an overlay `div` with `onClick` event. It triggers `onOverlayHandle` function. Inside that function, I am logging a simple text and then I redirect user to `/feedback` route. So when I click on `overlay` div, it logs the message but it does not redirect user to specified route.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect after the click you should use history.

```
import { Link, useParams, Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

const SampleComponent = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const onOverlayHandle = () => {
    console.log('overlay clicked');
    history.push("/feedback");
  }

    return (
    <div className='view dialog'>
      <div className='form'>
        <h3>CONTENTS</h3>
      </div>
      <div className='overlay' onClick={onOverlayHandle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to use Redirect you need to create a state variable and then conditionally return the Redirect.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

const SampleComponent = (props) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const onOverlayHandle = () => {
    console.log('overlay clicked');
    setRedirect(true);
  }

  if(redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/feedback" />
  }

    return (
    <div className='view dialog'>
      <div className='form'>
        <h3>CONTENTS</h3>
      </div>
      <div className='overlay' onClick={onOverlayHandle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thats great is worked fine but it does not refresh the `feedback` component. How can I refresh automatically when use is redirected to `feedback` route. I am using `Redirect` with you approach this time.

Comment: When you Redirect to a page, the page it's rendered so it's refreshed, it's the same as using a Link to navigate to another page. Maybe the problem is in the way you access the data inside your feedback component