# Component is not refreshed upon Redirect route in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I posted this same code a while ago with a different question which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141733/redirect-route-does-not-redirect-to-a-specified-route-in-reactjs). This question is different. Now I can Redirect to `feedback` route but I want refresh `feedback` component. Currently it is not refreshing. Below is the same code.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

const SampleComponent = (props) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const onOverlayHandle = () => {
    console.log('overlay clicked');
    setRedirect(true);
  }

  if(redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/feedback" />
  }

    return (
    <div className='view dialog'>
      <div className='form'>
        <h3>CONTENTS</h3>
      </div>
      <div className='overlay' onClick={onOverlayHandle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the `feedback` component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';

import { reviewsAction } from '../../actions/feedback';
import { getCookie } from '../../utils/cookies';

import ViewFeedbacksComponent from './viewFeedbacksComponent';
import AddFeedbackComponent from './addFeedbackComponent';

import './reviews.scss';

const FeedbackComponent = (props) => {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(reviewsAction({
      role: getCookie('role'),
      userID: getCookie('userID'),
    }))
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.getReviews.hasOwnProperty('response') && props.getReviews.response !== undefined) {
      if (Array.isArray(props.getReviews.response)) {
        setReviews(props.getReviews.response);
      } else {
        setMessage(props.getReviews.response.message);
      }
    }
  }, [props]);

    return (
    <div className='reviews'>
      <div className='navigation'>
        <button className='btn danger'>Logout</button>
      </div>
      <h3>Feedbacks Page</h3>
      {
        message !== ''
        ?
        <p>{message}</p>
        : 
        <table className='table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Job Knowledge</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {reviews.map(review => (
              <tr key={review._id}>
                <td className='name__column capitalize'>
                  {review.employeeName}
                </td>
                <td className='knowledge__column'>
                  {review.jobKnowledge}
                </td>
                <td className='actions'>
                  <Link to={`/feedback/view-feedbacks/${review._id}`} className='link'>View Feedbacks</Link>
                </td>
                <td className='actions'>
                  <Link to={`/feedback/add-feedback/${review._id}`} className='link'>Add Feedback</Link>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      }
      <Route path={`${url}/view-feedbacks/:id`}><ViewFeedbacksComponent /></Route>
      <Route path={`${url}/add-feedback/:id`}><AddFeedbackComponent /></Route>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (state);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FeedbackComponent);
```

Comment: Show code of redirect 'feedback' component.

Comment: @Robert I added the `feedback` component.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by refreshing? unmounting and mounting? are you sure it's not always mounted? hard to tell without seeing where its used

Comment: @andrewgi by refreshing I mean it should dispatch `reviewsAction` inside `useEffect` again to load up to date data and display it. Currently it is not dispatching that action. Any idea?

Comment: put console log in component (anywhere) to check that is run rerender. And put second one in useEffect related to dispatch. I suspect that is not rerendering becose nothing was changed (disptach is the same) if you wolud have some user id in global context or passed through props to component then it would know that id was changed and it have to fire once again get coocieks

Comment: When I add `props` as dependency to `reviewsAction` useEffect then the component is re-rendering all the time I mean there is an infinite loop.

Comment: Is the `SampleComponent` a model dialog over `FeedbackComponent`? may the route was already loaded? You could try doing `location.reload()` if that's the case

Comment: @Om3ga yes in that case your component will need to be unmounted and then mounted again when hit with the redirect since dispatch never changes. Can you post your routes? I suspect the Feedback component is always there but you don't see it when sample component is rendered

Comment: Why you add props ??? just destruct need value from props in your case {getReviews}. I don't get why response is nested in getRewies. you should pass just value to this component and unpack it in component which make call (parent). Then each time reviews change then you component will rerender.